# Updating the source of a Listbox with a multibinding

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to get a multi-bound listbox to call the convert back method when items inside it change.  Specifically I have a datatemplate that maps each entry to a checkbox and I'd like the source to be updated whenever a box is checked.

```
 <ListBox x:Name="listBoxEdit" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="3" Height="100"  >
     <ListBox.ItemsSource>
         <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource selectedLoadsConverter}" >
             <Binding Path="AvailableLoads"/>
             <Binding Path="CurrentUnit"/>
         </MultiBinding>
     </ListBox.ItemsSource>
         <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <CheckBox Content="{Binding Item1}" IsChecked="{Binding Item2}"/>
             </DataTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

I know the problem lies in the fact that I'm binding to to the ItemsSource property which is never actually being updated by the checkbox changing, but I can't figure out a good way to push the updates up to the source.

Comment: [UpdateSourceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx)=PropertyChanged

Comment: I have tried that with no luck, I believe the converter never gets called because the ItemsSource never actually changes.  Right now I have the problem addressed in code behind (using the click event on the checkbox) but that's less than ideal.